# Is my key really ignored in my PHP CURL SSL call?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm using a TestApi to check SSL connection using PEM and KEY files.
However, if I edit my private key, it seems I can get the header anyway.
Should it really behave like this? I never get an error thrown regarding the key. I do however get errors when the certifications are not right.

I always get a

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 5983 Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 21:10:33 GMT Server: TheServer   TheServer BUS RP interface Version: 4.0.0

followed by a sh*tload of text from `htmlentities`.

```
$url = "https://mylink?wsdl";

// cert file/pass (same as pfx above but converted to pem and key)
$cert_file = "myPemfile.pem";
$cert_password = "myKeyfile.key"; // I've intentionally set the wrong key... but God knows why it still works

// server cert which we trust (this is needed when using VERIFYPEER below)
$cert_server = "serverCA.pem";

$ch = curl_init();

$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, //return output
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true, // just to see header response
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // cant figure this out yet (probably means internal redirect within $url)
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2, //ok
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true, // yes
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => $cert_server, // set it
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)', // ? seems this is needed
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => false, // change to true/false if you want/(dont want) verbose
    CURLOPT_URL => $url , //set
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $cert_file,  //set
    //CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE => 'PEM', // well.. default is PEM anyway
    CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $cert_password, //set
    );
curl_setopt_array($ch , $options);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$output)
{
    echo "Curl Error : " . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo "<br /> db: output unparsed :<br />" . $output . "<br /> db: DONE <br /><br />";

    echo htmlentities($output);

}
```

Comment: i have always been a little hazy on this but found no need to set certs\keys but find curl takes care of it by itself.

Comment: In this case, I don't even need to point out a keyfile and it will be ok. I donnu if it's just due to the fact that it's a testApi ..perhaps? But what you are saying "curl takes care of it by itself" doesn't really sound pretty convincing nor make any sense... but.. I donnu maybe you're right

Comment: well your browser takes care of it by itself right? curl has a cert bundle just like browsers do. But like i said a little hazy i do use curl to hit api end points over https with out adding anything special for it being https vs http.

Comment: Ok.. that makes more sense. But ignoring the private key? Really? I'm leaning more towards the fact that I effed up something here. Either codewise or thoughtwise

Comment: And I just saw that the PEM file contains the private key... why would I then need a separate KEY file?... huh...

Comment: let me know when you figure it out :-)

Comment: @Dagon , appareantly the separate key file is ignored when key already exists in PEM file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities which would fit your description:

- the server does not require client certificates at all. In this case it does not matter what client certificate and key you give because it will not be used anyway.
- the real key is already contained in the PEM file you've given for the certificate

Comment: Yes, I figured as much about the key being in the PEM file. I'm going to experiment with this and get back to you. I should be able to cut out the private key part from the PEM file right?

Comment: @niCkcAMel: yes, you can simple edit the file in a text editor and remove the part between and including `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- .... -----END PRIVATE KEY-----`.

Comment: Ooh ok, so the prefix and suffix  `PRIVATE KEY` needs to be present?

Comment: @niCkcAMel: this prefix and suffix belongs to the PEM encoding of the key and should be removed together with the key

Comment: I missed your "...including...". sorry my bad

Comment: yup.. that was it.